# Whose happines matters more ours or of others?

Tags: karma

Should we sacrifice our happiness and be sad for others happiness or sacrifice their happiness to make our self happy?

Comment: '''All spiritual practices are in vain if you close your eyes to suffering of others.'''

Comment: Your happiness matters most. But it takes tremendous wisdom to realize actually your happiness is actually in other's happiness.

Comment: Defeating our enemies would make them sad , so should we not do it?